# Understanding lambda substitution in Redex

Tags: lambda, racket, substitution, redex

Let us say I have the following defined in Redex:

```
(define-language L
    [e ::= (λ x e) (e e) x]
    [x ::= variable-not-otherwise-mentioned]
    #:binding-forms
    (λ x e #:refers-to x))
```

Now, I would think that the expression `(λ y x) x` means:

replace occurrence of `y` in `x` (inside braces in the above expression) with `x` (outside braces). And since there is no `y` in `x`, the answer should be just `x`. Then `(λ y x) x y` should return `x y`. But:

```
(default-language L)
(term (substitute (λ y x) x y))
'(λ y«0» y)
```

why does it return a function? And what does `y<<0>>` mean? Am I misunderstanding `term (substitute ..)`?

I didn't understand this result either:

```
(term (substitute (λ y x) x true))
'(λ y«1» true)
```

Could someone help me decipher this? I'm new to Racket/Redex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`y«0»` and `y«1»` simply mean that while the variable is named `y`, its a different `y` than the one passed in. The `#:refers-to` flag is used to make forms respect capture-avoiding substitution.

In general, the idea is this, what should the result of this program be:

```
((lambda (x) (lambda (y) x))
 y)
```

Should this program evaluate to `4` or `3`? If we use simple substitution, then we can say that the program reduces to:

```
(lambda (y) y)
```

Which is the identity function. This is noticeable if we, say, bound y to 5 and called the result:

```
(let* ([y 5]
       [f ((lambda (x) (lambda (y) x))
            y)])
  (f 6))
```

Here, we would expect the result to be `5`, even though we are passing `6` into `f`. This is because the `y` in the result is pointing to the first `y` in the `let*`. You can see this if you mouse of `y` in DrRacket.

To avoid this, rather than doing a simple substitution of all `x`s in the expression to `y`s, it renames all binders going down to new names, so instead you get:

```
(lambda (y«0») y)
```

And now its clear that the two `y`s in this expression are different.